# TKinter: making an "apply changes" or preview type of button

Tags: tkinter, python-3.3

I am working on a very large program and unfortunately I am not near my computer right now. So I will try to explain my problem, but if need be I can draw up a sample code later.

In my gui I want to offer the user the ability to choose between 10 different color themes. Each theme would change everything from the background, fonts, buttons, etc. The choices are listed out as radiobuttons. My plan was to have a .get () method grab the users choice, then run it through a function that assigns the colors to the application's class attributes. Then the color scheme is saved in a shelve as a user preference so it is the same each time the user opens the program. I would like to generate an "apply" button so the user can see what the color scheme will look like before finalizing their choice and saving it to file. My research has led me to a post on here by Mr. Oakley that advises the use of the .configure() method. This would be a massive endeavour to make configure lines to change all the widgets across all the different windows, toplevels, messageboxes, etc. I could do it, but it seems like their must be an easier way. Is there no method built into Tkinter to update or refresh a window with the new color assignments?

Comment: Is this using ttk's themed widgets?

Comment: No, using Tkinter, not ttk. Is there a solution in ttk?

Comment: This won't give you an instant solution, but it would be a good place to start: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk.html

Comment: After a cursory review, the ttk package looks like it may provide the exact solution. Thanks! If I find it does not, I'll reopen the thread and add a sample code.